How to align inset map (with coord_sf) in patchwork?
I'd like to plot an inset map in the top left corner of another map using package patchwork. Yet, when using coord_sf(), the alignment does not work anymore. How to solve this to ensure the inset map is placed in the top left corner and aligns with the borders of the big map?
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(iris) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  coord_sf()

p2 <- ggplot(iris) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = Petal.Width)) +
  coord_sf()

p1 + inset_element(p2, 0, 0.6, 0.4, 1, clip = TRUE, align_to = "panel")


Without coord_sf(), the plots are aligned correctly:


I'm not sure I understand your problem, since removing coord_sf() seems to solve the issue. However, I think the issue comes from the coord_sf() function itself. Have you tried looking at p2 directly? it's already all squished.

The problem is that I need to use coord_sf() for the correct ratio. This is just an example, the real maps look OK of course. It's not about the plot sizes but about the alignment.

I think the issue is linked to this squished aspect. I'm not well-versed enough in ggplot to dig into this, but I suspect that the 'non-alignment' is caused by the inset function relying on the full plot area (which has lost of surrounding white space that doesn't show when inset) rather than the actual defined ('squished') plot area

Perhaps there is a way to adjust the 'outer boundaries' of the plot to match the plotting area. That should fix the alignment

I think it is because coord_sf forces a 1:1 ratio of the x and y axes, so the four corners specified in the inset do not stretch the scale as they would for normal coordinates. If you just look at p2 with coord_sf it is the same tall thin shape that is getting inserted. You should set the axis limits of p2 to get the shape you want. The placement then seems to be centred in the box specified, depending on whether the shape is too tall or too wide.

You can do so with a helper function that checks whether the main plot's coordinate system is CoordSf or plain and adapts the left and bottom margin accordingly. Then, use geom_sf() only for actual spatial features.
library(rnaturalearth) ## to create example maps only
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

## create example plots:
map_of_europe <- ggplot(ne_countries(continent = 'Europe')) + geom_sf()
map_of_CH <- ggplot(ne_countries(country = 'Switzerland')) + geom_sf()
sepal_plot <- ggplot(iris) + geom_histogram(aes(x = Petal.Width))


## this function adapts the left and bottom offset to align with the
## coordinate system 'CoordSf' or plain of the main plot:

plot_with_inset <- \(main, inset, zoom){
  ## does the main plot have sf-coordinates?
  main_is_sf <- inherits(ggplot_build(main)$layout$coord, 'CoordSf')
  left <- ifelse(main_is_sf , -zoom/2, 0)
  bottom <- ifelse(main_is_sf, 1 - zoom, 1 - zoom/2)
  main + inset_element(inset, left, bottom, zoom, 1, align_to = 'full')
}

plot_with_inset(map_of_europe, sepal_plot, zoom = .5)


plot_with_inset(map_of_europe, map_of_CH, zoom = .3)


plot_with_inset(sepal_plot, map_of_europe, zoom = .5)



Bonus: you can query a plot's dimensions with packages {grid}, {gtable} and {cowplot}, the latter being another great package to compose plots. Example:
library(gtable)
library(grid)
library(cowplot)
get_dims <- \(p){
  Map(c(gtable_width, gtable_height),
      f = \(g) as_gtable(p) |> g() |>
        convertUnit('mm')
  ) |> unlist() |> sort() |> setNames(c('short', 'long'))
}

## > get_dims(map_of_europe)
##    short     long 
## 3.866058 8.644259 


To top-left-align an inset with a fixed aspect ratio (either because you used coord_sf or you set it in a theme), set the value for left to 0, bottom to whatever you want, right to bottom * 1/aspect_ratio and top to 1.

How do I find out about the correct ratio?

Erc: st_bbox will give a close approach if you inset a map (although the space required for axes labels will distort the ratio a bit). You can also work out the actual plot dimensions but that's not straightforward.

I think the key may be to to changing the alignment to full. When I was tinkering with this answer it looks like theme_void will move some the inset plot slightly. You may need to tinker with this a bit more
library(patchwork)
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(sf))
library(nycdogs)
library(ggplot2)

small_nyc = nyc_license |>
  filter(extract_year == 2016, breed_rc == "Pit Bull (or Mix)") |>
  mutate(total_pitbull = n(), .by = c(borough, breed_rc))

big_map_dat = left_join(nyc_zips, small_nyc, join_by(zip_code), relationship = 'many-to-many')

## just expanding this a bit 
big_nyc_map  = ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = big_map_dat, aes(fill = total_pitbull)) +
  coord_sf(ylim = c(40.4, 41), expand = FALSE) 

manhattan_dogs = nyc_license |>
  filter(extract_year == 2016, breed_rc == "Pit Bull (or Mix)",
  borough == 'Manhattan') |>
mutate(total_pitbull = n(), .by = zip_code)

rotatated_manhattan = nyc_zips |>
  filter(borough == 'Manhattan') |>
  left_join(manhattan_dogs, join_by(zip_code), relationship = 'many-to-many') |>
  st_transform("+proj=laea +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +lon_0=90 +lat_0=90") |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = total_pitbull)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none') +
  coord_sf(expand = FALSE)

 unrotated_manhattan  = nyc_zips |>
  filter(borough == 'Manhattan') |>
  left_join(manhattan_dogs, join_by(zip_code), relationship = 'many-to-many') |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = total_pitbull)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none') +
  coord_sf(expand = FALSE)

  

messed_with = big_nyc_map + inset_element(rotatated_manhattan, left = 0, bottom = 0.6, right = 0.4, top = 1, align_to = 'full', clip = FALSE)

not_messed_with = big_nyc_map + inset_element(unrotated_manhattan, left = 0, bottom = 0.6, right = 0.4, top = 1, align_to = 'full', clip = FALSE)

messed_with / not_messed_with


Created on 2024-07-18 with reprex v2.1.1
